# HippoCMS - Forms with Community Version

Tags: hippocms

I'm new at HippoCMS using and wonder how to implement forms for website users (in order to make a contact form for exemple). 
I'm aware that "Enterprise Forms" are a "Experience version" feature, but I heard about a plugin named "Easy Form" which would allow me to deal with my problem.
Unfortunaly, Easy Form seems to be obsolete. By the way, no sources are available today.

Does anybody know if it's possible to include forms with community version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For basic implementation, take a look to the documentation page 
https://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hst-2-forms.html